# WPF Datagrid or maybe something else that can have indents in the first column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a table with a bunch of data this is a small sample:

| Header - Object name | Waarde |
| --- | --- |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.Settings.Off | 0 |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.Standby | 0 |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.Cooling | 1 |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.Drying | 0 |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.Heating | 0 |
| ExportRoot.a80_02_00_01_Status.PrepDrain | 0 |

I wish to style this table in a way to where its more readable by removing the object parts and indenting the table like how it looks below.

```
| Header - Object name     | Waarde  |
|--------------------------|---------|
| ExportRoot               |         |
|   | a80_02_00_01_Status  |         |
|   |   | Settings         |         |
|   |   |   | Off          | 0       |
|   |   |   | Standby      | 0       |
|   |   |   | Cooling      | 1       |
|   |   |   | Drying       | 0       |
|   |   |   | Heating      | 0       |
|   |   |   | PrepDrain    | 0       |
```

Is there a way of doing this and if so what should I be looking for all I've found so far are tables with sub tables and that not exactly what I'm looking for. If anyone has an idea let me know I'm super lost.

Comment: First thing would be splitting your data so it gets the parts of the object name in columns, then generate the hierarchical data and finally display that  hierarchical data in a tree (check Ugur's answer for this step).

Comment: typing error cleptus but yes

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need a TreeListView:

There is one project on CodeProject that you can check:

[WPF TreeListView Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control)

There is also commercial products, like DevExpress:

[DevExpress TreeList View](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/9566/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/views/treelist-view)

Comment: I shall give this a go looks like the type of thing I'm looking for!